# Proving the alternate form of expression of the derivative of a function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, solution-verification

I am self-learning real analysis from Stephen Abbott's *Understanding Analysis*. Abbott's text has the following definition:

> A function $g:A\to\mathbf{R}$ is said to be differentiable at $c \in A$, if and only if the following limit exists and is finite.
>
> $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{g(x) - g(c)}{x - c} = g'(c)$$

Exercise 5.2.6 asks to prove an equivalent expression for the derivative of a function. It appears as a rather trivial exercise in Calculus, but is this proof correct and rigorous?

> [Abbot, 5.2.6] Let $g$ be defined on an interval $A$, and let $c \in A$.

> (a) Explain why $g'(c)$ in the definition 5.2.1 could be given by
> \begin{align*}
>     g'(c) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(c+h) - g(c)}{h}
> \end{align*}

> (b) Assume $A$ is open. If $g$ is differentiable at $c \in A$, show that
> \begin{align*}
>     g'(c) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(c+h) - g(c-h)}{2h}
> \end{align*}

***Proof.***

(a) Since, $A$ is an interval, any point belonging to $A$ may be an interior point or a boundary point. Assume that $c$ is a boundary point, then for all $\epsilon > 0$, the open interval $(c - \epsilon, c + \epsilon) \setminus \{c\}$ intersects $A$ in atleast one point and $A^C$ in atleast one point. Let $\Delta x$ be such that, either $(c + \Delta x) \in A$  or $(c - \Delta x) \in A$ where  $\Delta x < \epsilon$. Define

\begin{align*}
    h = \begin{cases}
    \Delta x & \text { if } c + \Delta x \in A \\
    -\Delta x & \text { if } c - \Delta x \in A
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}

then $(g(c+h)-g(c))/h$ exists and is well-defined.

Let $x = c + h$. Then, $x - h = c$. As $x \to c$, $h \to 0$. So, we can write,

\begin{align*}
    g'(c) &= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{g(c+h) - g(c)}{h}
\end{align*}

(b) If $A$ is open, there exists an $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of $x$ that is contained entirely in $A$. So, for all $h<\epsilon$, $(c + h, c - h)$ is contained in $A$.

\begin{align*}
    g'(c) &= \lim_{x \to c}\frac{g(x) - g(c)}{x - c}
\end{align*}

Let $x = c + h$. Then,
\begin{align*}
    g'(c) &= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{g(c + h) - g(c)}{h}
\end{align*}

Let $x = c - h$. Then,
\begin{align*}
    g'(c) &= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{g(c - h) - g(c)}{(-h)}\\
    &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(c) - g(c-h)}{h}
\end{align*}

Adding the two equations,
\begin{align*}
    2g'(c) &= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{g(c + h) - g(c-h)}{h}\\
    g'(c) &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(c + h) - g(c - h)}{2h}
\end{align*}